# Spark on Hive progress bar stuck at 10%

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

Recently we have upgraded to Spark 1.6 and trying to use SparkQL as default query engine for Hive. Spark Gateway role is added on the same machine with HiveServer2 and Spark On Yarn Service is enabled. However when I run a query like following:

```
SET hive.execution.engine=spark;
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/someuser/spark_test_job' SELECT country, COUNT(*) FROM country_date GROUP BY country;
```

We see the job is Accepted by Yarn, resources allocated and status says it is running, however, it shows a constant progress of 10% and does not go any further in either Hue or Yarn UI. 
[image: From Hue]
If we check Spark UI job is complete and I actually see an output on HDFS: 
[image: output from Spark UI]
Did anyone run into similar issue? Any clues how to debug such behaviour? 
I use Cloudera CDH 5.12

Comment: Looks like your execution ended already. And the session with spark and hive still open. The execution progress in yarn with spark and other type of data are little different. This usually happens when you are using spark-shell that the progress is always 10%. If Hive open a connection like this per session, this probably the problem. Tez work a little bit different than that.

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim so is there a way to close the session? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. There was a [patch released](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14162) recently to fix this. Floats between bug and feature:

> When a Hive session is initiated, and a query is submitted to the
>   Spark processing engine, Hive maintains one or more Spark Executors on
>   the cluster until the session is terminated.  The initial setup of the
>   Spark processing engine is time intensive.  To avoid the overhead of
>   having to create a new Spark processing engine for each query
>   submitted, Hive maintains a Spark Application Master (YARN Spark
>   Driver) and one or more Spark Executors for each Hive session.  The
>   trade-off however is that the Spark components will consume resources
>   on YARN even though they may be in an idle phase, between queries, for
>   long periods of time.

So to fix this without patch you should either terminate Hive session or switch back to MapReduce QL engine once a query is done. If you use Hue, you have an only second option.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing this from my past experience. Please read this post:

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Hive-on-Spark-tasks-never-finish/td-p/52565

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Will try that tomorrow.